# re-arrange my input table in excel using VPA to get the the required output format

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel with data listed in one format, but I need it to be arranged in different format to be able to load it in another software.
I have two tables the first one is input data and the second is output.
The data in there is just a sample of my full data set.
the missing value of -9999 will be added into my output when DHGP_UPPER  and / or when DHGT_UPPER not available
your help is appreciated, as I am planning to learn excel macros :-)

[image]

**Input table**
[image: input table]

**Output table**
[image: output table]

Comment: How does it convert from one to the other?  Where does `-9999` come into it?  `6, 7, 8, 9` are listed in the first column under name - something to do with the date?  `*BHP` has the value `4241.935759`  where's that come from?  Why does `PO3H_LK3` have 5 written under it?  From the info you've given it looks impossible to convert from one to the other.

Comment: I have updated the output table with the right name and data linking it to the input table, and updated the description with how the -9999 come in the output table.